# How to test a function which consumes a callback? Or how to defer the assertion?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I use Jest to test a function which generates a JSON Web Token. It seems that I can't assert the value since when I assert, the callback hasn't been executed yet.

```
const issueJWT = function issueJWT(req, res, next) {
    jwt.sign(signUser, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.locals.token = token;
        next();
    });
};
```

This is my test, I mock the request and response, then assert the result:

```
test('Should return a JWT with proper value if nothing wrong happened', () => {
    issueJWT(request, response, mockNext);

    const JWT = response.locals.token;
    const tokenPayload = jwt.decode(JWT, { complete: true }).payload;
    expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('iat');
    expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('exp');
    expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('id');
});
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of null

How to make it work?
According to my knowledge, I think the callback is at the task queue which
 means it will be executed when nothing is in the event loop, right? I wanna find a way to defer my assertion, but don't know how...

Thanks for the tips, I use the `done`, now the test could pass, but the problem is, whenever there is a problem, the error message doesn't make any sense... Any problem to my solution?

```
test('Should return a JWT with proper value if nothing wrong happened',  (done) => {
    const callback = () => {
        const JWT = response.locals.token;
        const tokenPayload = jwt.decode(JWT, { complete: true }).payload;

        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('iat');
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('exp');
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('id');
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('iss');
        done();
    };

    issueJWT(request, response, callback);
});
```

The error is now:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html

Comment: To be fair, @FelixKling, those docs aren't great if you're using callbacks instead of promises.

Comment: @Paul: Not sure I understand. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling I mean that I'm dumb and read the documentation too quickly, totally skipping the Callback block. :P.  Though this is an interesting case, because the 'done' pattern used by both Mocha and Jest in this case doesn't really apply, as the callback pattern assumes you're testing the function that exposes the callback as a parameter.  I can see how he'd be confused.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. Read that doc, and add done, works now. But somehow the error message is not right...Any tips on this?

Comment: That seems to indicate that the callback passed to `jwt.sign` is never called. Do you expect that to work in a test? If not you have to mock that function and make the mock call the callback.

Comment: @FelixKling, strange, I mock that next() and asssert that, it has been called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with some help from @felixKling getting me to actually *read* the docs, you need to do something like this:

```
test('Should return a JWT with proper value if nothing wrong happened', done => {
    issueJWT(request, response, (e) => {
        const JWT = response.locals.token;
        const tokenPayload = jwt.decode(JWT, { complete: true }).payload;
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('iat');
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('exp');
        expect(tokenPayload).toHaveProperty('id');
        done();
    });
});
```

I'm not on my dev box so I can't test this, but basically the idea is that you use the 'done' parameter to the test callback to signal that the test is waiting on async code.  The test framework will basically wait for your test to call that callback before exiting.

In this case, your `next()` call from `issueJWT` is what we're waiting on firing before checking to see if the various objects were updated.  If you were not using `next()` in  your middleware, you'd likely need to mock whatever response method you're calling instead (e.g. `response.end()`) to do your tests.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get the result now, the new problem is that the error message is not related to my problem...Any hint for this?

Comment: You should really open another question about that.  But generally it's just what the error says; the test took longer than the default timeout interval.  That means either increase the interval, or else look at your plumbing to make sure you're actually calling the callback in all code branches.